# Error: Unable to find Mono. Ensure that Mono's '/bin' folder is added to your environment's PATH variable (on MacOS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, mono

I set (Omnisharp: Use Global Mono) to "always."
and I typed the latest in ("omnisharp.path":) "latest" but I'm facing this error

[ERROR] Error: Unable to find Mono. Ensure that Mono's '/bin' folder is added to your environment's PATH variable.

Comment: Did you added the path to the bin folder to your PATH Environment Variable? If you are on windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)

Comment: No , how can I add it ? It was worked without problems, but I restarted the device and this problem appeared . I use mac

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and check if path is added with

```sh
echo $PATH
```

if the path to Mono bin Folder is missing **add it with** (replace [PATH to the mono bin Folder] with your path), normally the path is `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin`:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:[PATH to the mono bin Folder]
```